# C: STM32F4 discovery software debouncing user button interrupt

Tags: c, stm32f4discovery, debouncing

I'm trying to program an STM32F4 discovery board so that the user button can be used to alter the state of the program via interrupt. My state machine code and the interrupt is working fine, however the button-presses/interrupts need debouncing.

I'm mostly a novice when it comes to STM32F4 programming and so I'm not sure what the most effective/practical method of debouncing would be in this case. Am I better off creating debounce code where I'm checking for interrupts or should I be doing this inside the interrupt itself? I've tried using the timer to count ticks (from inside the timer and separately I tried this where the interrupt is checked in the code) but it doesn't seem to work unless the button is pressed rapidly rather than held down. Similarly using the delay (HAL library: HAL_Delay()) function doesn't work as intended in the main loop and freezes the program if used in the interrupt.

This is the code for my timer and the push button interrupt:

```
void
HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback (TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if (htim->Instance == htim3.Instance)
  {
    start_loop = 1;
  }
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_0)
  {
    buttonPressed = 1;
  }
}
```

This the my main loop / state machine code:

```
switch (status)
    {
      case 0: // WAIT
        if (buttonPressed == 1)
        {
          buttonPressed = 0;
          status = 1; // go to SET
        }
        break;
      case 1:  // SET
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // loop twice for DMA ret val
        resultStatus = HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint16_t*) &data, 1);
        if (resultStatus != 0)
        {
          printf("-> ERROR: HAL_ADC_Start_DMA() call failed (status = %d)\n", resultStatus);
        }
        duration = 5 + round((10.0/255)*data[0]); // calc duration (5-15 s)
        endTime = loop_count + duration * 100;  // for 20/60 s run time
        status = 2; // go to RUN
        break;
      case 2: // RUN
        if (loop_count >= endTime)
        {
          status = 4; // go to END
        }
        else if (buttonPressed == 1)
        {
          buttonPressed = 0;
          status = 3; // go to PAUSE
        }
        else
        {
          // Blue LED ON
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOD, LED_BLU, 1);
        }
        //  Motor ON
        break;
      case 3: // PAUSE
        pause_count++;
        if (buttonPressed == 1)
        { // go to RUN
          endTime = endTime + pause_count;
          pause_count = 0;
          buttonPressed = 0;
          status = 2; // return to RUN
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOD, LED_RED, 0);
        }
        else if (pause_count >= 20000/TIMER_PERIOD)
        { // go to END
          status = 4;
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOD, LED_RED, 0);
        }
        else
        {
          //  Red LED pattern
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOD, LED_RED, 1);
        }
        break;
      case 4: // END
        //  Blue LED OFF
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOD, LED_BLU, 0);
        //  Motor OFF
        break;
    }
}
```